# Images exported from ArcGIS Online as File Geodatabase inaccessible to ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, arcgis-online, file-geodatabase

I am a new user of ArcGIS Online.

I have a system that includes features and images of the objects and I use Esri ArcGIS for Desktop to perform data collecting.

Before exporting the whole database as FGDB I use attachment management to download the images as FGDB zip file.

How can I reach the images in the exported FGDB file using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Comment: Are you trying to access the data inside the zip file?

Comment: I exract the zip file, the zip file includes features, tables and also image files, i want to reach images that taken at the field works.

Comment: See if this helps https://geonet.esri.com/thread/54142. Mike Minami method works always